# remove the workflow via the Java code at bootstartup

Tags: java, workflow, alfresco, bootstrapping

I need to remove the workflow via the Java code at bootstartup. My code works correctly at runtime, but it throw exception if I run it at boot startup. What should I do to remove the workflow at bootstartup via the Java code?

for example:

*my-example-context.xml:*

```
<bean id="my-example" class="MyExamle" init-method="init">
        <property name="workflowService">
            <ref bean="WorkflowService"/>
        </property>
</bean>
```

*MyExamle.java:*

```
public class MyExamle {
    ...
    private WorkflowService workflowService;

    public void init() {
        PropertyCheck.mandatory(this, "workflowService", workflowService);

        AuthenticationUtil.runAs(new AuthenticationUtil.RunAsWork<Integer>() {
            @Override
            public Integer doWork() throws Exception {
                 Integer count = 0;
                 WorkflowDefinition reviewDef = workflowService.getDefinitionByName(
                            "activiti$activitiReview"
                 );
                 List<WorkflowInstance> workflowInstanceList = workflowService.getActiveWorkflows(
                            reviewDef.getId()
                 );
                 count = workflowInstanceList.size();
                 for (WorkflowInstance workflowInstance : workflowInstanceList) {
                          workflowService.deleteWorkflow(
                                workflowInstance.getId()
                          );
                 }
                 return count;
            }
        }, AuthenticationUtil.getSystemUserName());
    }
    ...
}
```

this code throw exception: org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceException: Namespace prefix wf is not mapped to a namespace URI

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mrem-extention-bootstartup' defined in URL [jar:file:/C:/Alfresco/tomcat/webapps/alfresco/WEB-INF/lib/moldavia-rem.jar!/alfresco/extension/mrem-bootstartup-context.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceException: Namespace prefix wf is not mapped to a namespace URI
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:288)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:190)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:580)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:895)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:425)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
    at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
    at org.alfresco.web.app.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:63)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4135)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:4630)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:791)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:771)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:546)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptor(HostConfig.java:637)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployDescriptors(HostConfig.java:563)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:498)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.start(HostConfig.java:1277)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.lifecycleEvent(HostConfig.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1053)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.start(StandardHost.java:785)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.start(ContainerBase.java:1045)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine.start(StandardEngine.java:445)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.start(StandardService.java:519)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.start(StandardServer.java:710)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:581)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: org.alfresco.service.namespace.NamespaceException: Namespace prefix wf is not mapped to a namespace URI
    at org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName.createQName(QName.java:99)
    at org.alfresco.service.namespace.QName.createQName(QName.java:121)
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowQNameConverter.convertNameToQName(WorkflowQNameConverter.java:103)
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowQNameConverter.convertNameToQName(WorkflowQNameConverter.java:85)
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowQNameConverter.mapNameToQName(WorkflowQNameConverter.java:71)
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowObjectFactory.getTaskTypeDefinition(WorkflowObjectFactory.java:409)
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowObjectFactory.createTaskDefinition(WorkflowObjectFactory.java:209)
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.ActivitiTypeConverter.getTaskDefinition(ActivitiTypeConverter.java:155)
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.ActivitiTypeConverter.convert(ActivitiTypeConverter.java:144)
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.activiti.ActivitiWorkflowEngine.getDefinitionByName(ActivitiWorkflowEngine.java:487)
    at org.alfresco.repo.workflow.WorkflowServiceImpl.getDefinitionByName(WorkflowServiceImpl.java:342)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:309)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:183)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:150)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.invoke(AlwaysProceedMethodInterceptor.java:34)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.security.permissions.impl.ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.invoke(ExceptionTranslatorMethodInterceptor.java:46)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.alfresco.repo.audit.AuditMethodInterceptor.invoke(AuditMethodInterceptor.java:147)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:110)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:202)
    at $Proxy71.getDefinitionByName(Unknown Source)
    at ru.moldavia.alfresco.workflow.WorkflowFactory.removeAllActivitiReviewWorkflow(Unknown Source)
    at ru.moldavia.alfresco.workflow.WAO.removeAllNotificationWorkflows(Unknown Source)
    at ru.moldavia.alfresco.workflow.bootstartup.WorkflowBootstartupExtention.extend(Unknown Source)
    at ru.moldavia.alfresco.bootstartup.ExtentionBootstartup.runExtentions(Unknown Source)
    at ru.moldavia.alfresco.bootstartup.ExtentionBootstartup.init(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeCustomInitMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1544)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1485)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 37 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think exception you provided is not related to your question. Check your data model definition.

In all cases - back to your question - try to use onBootstrap() instead of init(), just extend [AbstractLifecycleBean](http://www.springsurf.org/sites/1.0.0.CI-SNAPSHOT/apidocs/org/springframework/extensions/surf/util/AbstractLifecycleBean.html) class and Override onBootstrap(ApplicationEvent event) and onShutdown(ApplicationEvent event). There may be uninitialized parts of Alfresco system while calling init().

Comment: I use default "Review and approval of content using Activiti workflow engine" workflow, so data model definition is okay. Also this code is working properly at runtime. I try to use "onBootstrap()", "@PostConstruct" and "init-method", but aplication throw NamespaceException. Guess, the workflow models is loading later, but I don't know how listing this event :(

Comment: ok; which line throws that exception? but first try onBootstrap(), it solved my issues some time ago too :-)

Comment: I agree - you'll want to use onBootstrap(). Until the bootstrap, not all the beans will be defined and initialised

Comment: yes, you're right, with "onBootstrap()", everything is working properly, thanks a lot.